# iOS Gmail app html template white-space wrapping is not working

Tags: html, css, gmail, html-email

I can't get `white-space: pre-wrap` to work properly in gmail ios app – text overflows the container. You can see the problem below:

[image: screenshot]

I've tried setting the width explicitly. The problem only occurs on iOS Gmail app.

Here's the code that reproduces the problem:

```html
<div style="width: 100vw;overflow-wrap: break-word;word-wrap: break-word;-ms-word-break: break-all;word-break: break-all;word-break: break-word;white-space: pre-wrap;display: block;max-width: 700px;color: #666666;font-family: helvetica, sans-serif;line-height: 25.6px;font-size: 16px;original-line-height: 1.6; background-color: #ccc">
  <p style="margin: 0; text-align: justify; font-size: 16px !important; line-height: 25px; background-color: #ddd;">Liiorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
</div>
```

Any ideas are more than welcome!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Did you try placing the paragraph element? It maybe a div thing but try putting the paragraph inside a table and see if it works different.

Comment: Set padding to parent DIV and check. i think it will work.

Comment: Padding did not help, text still overflows.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove all of these styles from the `div`

`overflow-wrap: break-word;word-wrap: break-word;-ms-word-break: break-all;word-break: break-all;word-break: break-word;white-space: pre-wrap;original-line-height: 1.6;`

`overflow-wrap` and `word-break` aren't supported in Gmail and it looks like `white-space:pre-wrap` is causing the strange spacing issues.

I'd also recommend changing the `line-height` to a round number (25px)